# Can HTML iframes inherit css and javascript data

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if HTML iframes could inherit CSS data from their parent:

Main.html

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
     .highlight{
       background: #008fcc;
      }
   </style>
  </head>
 <body>
   <iframe src='frame.html'></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

frame.html

```
hello <font class='highlight'>
```

Comment: No, they can't. However magic can happen in <= IE7

Comment: No magic can happen in IE... only curses.

Answer (score 14):

**Short answer:** No, `iframe`s **generically** can't inherit/access styles/scripts from their parent page.

**Long answer:** You can't change anything in the styles or execute scripts inside an `iframe` *if* it's coming from another domain (you can't even read its DOM contents via JavaScript).

On the other hand, if it's coming from the same domain as your parent page, you can change styles of elements or execute scripts, by doing something similar to this in your parent page (this example uses jQuery, but it can be written in plain JavaScript):

```
$("#iframe_id").contents().find("#some_div").css({color: "rgb(0, 162, 232)"}); //changed style of a div inside the iframe
```

To execute a function defined inside the `iframe`:

```
$("#iframe_id").contents().document.functionName(functionParams);
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain this with the html5 **seamless** boolean parameter on the iframe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe

But currently it isn't fully implemented in any modern browser.

The simpler solution is to put all your CSS in a separate file and inculde it both in the main page and in the iframed page.

Comment: This parameter is now removed http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_seamless.asp