# How to prevent CSS in dynamically added HTML content from overriding my JSP's CSS content?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a **JSP** (a header, a body area, a footer, all with it's own **CSS**).

The body area is dynamically populated with **HTML** content from a database (it is archived mailing list emails).

The problem is, sometimes the email from the db is a fully-formatted HTML document with it's own **CSS**.

And sometimes that **CSS** (ex. `a:link { color: #000;}`) overrides the **CSS** in my **JSP** (ex. `a:link { color: #FFF;}`).

Is there a way to contain the wrap the dynamically loaded **HTML** in it's own container or something so it won't override the "external" **CSS**?

Comment: Is this a question of CSS specificity? Just chuck in a bunch of `!important` tags like I do ;)  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Sounds like a usecase for an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: @ne1410s Why would you ever do that. `!important` is for either overriding something's specificity (think shorthand rules like `.rel{ position:relative !important; }` where the only logical use of them implies you don't want it overridden ever) or for userstyles. ***Don't be that guy throwing `!important` everywhere in normal css. Nobody likes that guy.***

Comment: @NicoO You should post that as an answer because this is pretty much the poster child use case for an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrapping the information from the DB in `<iframe>` tags should be all that is necessary to avoid the DB content's styles overriding the rest of the page's styles. This is because iframes function as a new browsing context, and will not be able to send anything additional up. However, if you need your styles to propagate into it, iframe will not be able to help- or at least, not by itself.

There is an attribute called `seamless` in the works that will potentially enable that, but browser support is poor (re: currently nobody big implements it), and it seems like it might need to be paired with another setting to prevent its CSS from escaping the iframe if I'm reading [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) right (the [spec itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-iframe-seamless) does not seem to imply this).

If you need to be able to have parent affect the content of the iframe, [this question over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235806/can-html-iframes-inherit-css-and-javascript-data) should be able to help. TLDR from there, you can force it by targeting the iframe itself in javascript assuming the content is not external, but CSS propagation is not going to be possible without adding your own style includes.

In the future, it might also be possible to use "scoped stylesheets" ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) | [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped)), to where all you'd have to do is toss `scoped` onto any `<style>` tag in the file, however, you would still have any js executing on the full scope, and technically-invalid HTML (`<body>` inside `<body>`, etc) whenever you fetch a full page.

For more detailed information about iframes, see [the mdn on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Also: `Nico O` from the comments on the question deserves the beer for answering, I just formalized it and added the note on scoped stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "!important" in your desired CSS file.

```
a:link {
  color:green!important;
}
```

so that nothing can override it, even inline codes.

[Check it live here](https://jsfiddle.net/pLfsfxa3/)

Comment: Just a note, but adding `!important` doesn't make something unable to be overridden, it just makes it harder.  Other styles farther down with `!important` will still "win" or something with enough specificity.

Comment: Doing this also makes you that guy that puts `!important` all over the place. Don't do that, it's the css equivalent to herpes when you're trying to maintain it. Fix it properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right... Other styles with "!important" will win if they are located **after this one**. It just makes it harder. Your comment was upvoted as helpful. Thank you.