# Chrome text rendering when using transforms on parent element

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a very simple transform on div element. Inside of it is few lines of text. Text renders fine on Firefox and IE, but it is not looking good in Chrome. I tried changing -webkit-font-smoothing, but that didn't help either.

```
.text-holder{position: absolute;top: 0;width: 30rem;height: 20rem;margin-right:   auto;margin-left: auto;left: 0;right: 0;-webkit-transform:rotate(-4.6deg);-moz-   transform:rotate(-4.6deg); transform: rotate(-4.6deg);}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FFA6b/

Comment: There is a  good answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867574/chrome-not-antialiasing-text

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to explain why, but adding perspective solves the issue:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(999px) rotate(-4.6deg);
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFA6b/1/)**