# CSS transformed (rotated) text looks not anti-aliased in Chrome and Firefox (Windows)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, html-rendering, text-rendering

If I apply a rotation to a text, it will not render anti-aliased in Firefox and Chrome (only in Windows) but it renders correctly in IE. Also, it renders correctly in Chrome and Firefox in Mac OS X.

Here are screenshots comparing three browsers in my Windows 8:

http://d.pr/i/9qeg (Chrome)

http://d.pr/i/r8i0 (Firefox)

http://d.pr/i/crZ7 (IE10)

The CSS transformations for above is simply

```
transform: rotate(-1.5deg) translateY(-2px);
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sa6Nb/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: This may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/q/20721791/1926369

Comment: Your images are dead links.

Comment: Sorry they were in my Droplr but I deleted my account.

Answer (score 1):

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sa6Nb/4/)

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

You can try using `translate3d`. As far as i know it triggers hardware acceleration for an elements rendering process. You can see the difference in the fiddle (at least in chrome)

Comment: Which browser is this screenshot from? It works fine for me using chrome. I'm not sure if there's a solution for firefox at all.

Comment: This screenshot was taking using Google Chrome version 31.0.1650.63 m. The same that I used to take the screenshots in my question.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Chrome 32 (beta) and Windows XP,I know, it's old ;-) Perhaps your hardware acceleration is not enabled?

Comment: As of Jan/2017, this looks non-legible on an updated Firefox on Win7/Win8. Fine on Chrome on Win7. IE11 uses a strange fallback font, even worse than Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in your class:

```
.your-class{
   text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
```

Comment: Text shadow doesn't help for lack of anti-aliasing and applied on large portion of text may just slow down rendering.