# How to prevent Chrome from switching to grayscale anti-aliasing?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following page: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujkd6a27/4/).
As it stands, Chrome (47.0.2526.106 m) renders the fixed header text using gray-scale anti-aliasing:

[image]

While I want to maintain the "default" anti-aliasing you get without using any kind of 3D transforms:

[image]

In the linked fiddle, this is possible using these options:

- Removing `transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(-30deg);` from `.img`
- Removing `z-index: 999;` from the `#header` (for whatever reason this does not work in fiddle, so you have to show it in a dedicated browser tab using the copy-pasta code below)
- Removing `position: fixed;` from the `#header` (also does not work in fiddle)

However, all these options have a huge visual impact on other parts of the page which I want to avoid. So my question is, how can I keep the "default" anti-aliasing (whatever the proper term for this type of AA is), while also being able to use z-index/fixed position/rotateY?

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
  blah BLAH blah
</div>

<div class="img"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0 #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(-30deg);
    background: black;
}
```

**.html file** (for the z-index/position trick)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            #header {
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 999;
                background: #ccc;
                box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0 #000;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .img {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(-30deg);
                background: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
          blah BLAH blah
        </div>

        <div class="img"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to ask... Why does sub-pixel font rendering matter so much to you?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Because the text looks blurry on my monitor without it. [see for yourself](http://s28.postimg.org/exk82ymfd/blurry_text.png)

Comment: *possible* duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867574/chrome-not-antialiasing-text

Comment: @JasonHeine How is this a duplicate? The linked issue has been fixed since Chrome 37, while my bug is still very much present in Chrome 47. Furthermore, my issue explicitly mentions 3D rendering as the culprit, which the linked post does not mention at all.

Comment: @Paya which is why I had italicized *possible*. Just being helpful man :)

Comment: This link isn't an answer to this question, but it helped with what I was trying to achieve (proper subpixel antialiasing on a canvas element) https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161474