# Font looks more bold in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

I am using below font-family for body

```
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600 !important;
```

It looks perfect for chrome but it looks more bold in IE(all version) than chrome browser.

Comment: It could be zoom issues, anti-aliasing and how IE render font in general. Can you post any sample screenshots of these fonts?

Comment: sorry i am not able to upload images .but it is not zooming issue, may be anti-aliasing or something else

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Sans Google Web Fonts Rendering in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114417/open-sans-google-web-fonts-rendering-in-chrome)

Comment: actually this is google font