# SVG isn't always sharp

Tags: image, svg, zooming

The SVG logo on this [site](http://www.bastards-design.de/sebastian/#service) doesn't look sharp on every zoom level. I read once, that SVG is just sharp on a multiple of its original size. But when I rightclick on the graphic and display it alone (without an img tag around it), it looks sharp on every possible zoom. There is no width or height given to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Firefox renders the SVG to an image when referenced via an `<img>` tag. [Use an `<object>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files)

Comment: This works well. The only drawback is, that the user (this is a wordpress theme) cant upload other image formats anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in Firefox.
Try to set the image `width` to `100%` and `height` to the actual height of the `SVG` and this will solve the issue.

For Instance.

```
img{width:100%;
   height:xxpx; /* Where 'xx' is the value of the image height in pixels */
   }
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: You are right, this only appears in firefox. But your sollution does not work. Maybe its because my logo has digits behind the comma. I will try it with an svg, that has a whole number height and width.

Comment: But the inspect is showing me a width and height of 127px by 127px. You can just put this height and apply a width of 100%. - @Lord_Mord

Comment: That is the width and height of the svg viewport, but the img tag itself has no given height and width. I added height:127px and width:100% to CSS, but without effect.