# How to use external defs in SVG to inject identificators into includer's scope

Tags: svg

I have such a working main.svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs id ="mydefs">
    <marker id="markerEnd" markerWidth="15" markerHeight="15" refX="7" refY="7" orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,0 l7,7 l-7,7" style="stroke: #000000;fill: none;"/>
    </marker>
</defs>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#markerEnd)"/>
</svg>
```

Now I wish to move defs into a separated file.

defs.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs id ="mydefs">
    <marker id="markerEnd" markerWidth="15" markerHeight="15" refX="7" refY="7" orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,0 l7,7 l-7,7" style="stroke: #000000;fill: none;"/>
    </marker>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I could use: `marker-end="url(defs.svg#markerEnd)"`, but I wish to inject id's from defs.svg to main.svg to still use `marker-end="url(#markerEnd)"`.

**How do I change my main.svg to use marker identificator from external defs.svg?**

Such main.svg does not draw markerEnd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <use xlink:href="defs.svg#mydefs" />
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="defs.svg#mydefs" />
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#markerEnd)"/>
</svg>
```

I know about Cross Origin Policy for local files in Google Chrome and this is not the issue, I tested on many other browsers.

if you need HTML to test SVG:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body, object {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="main.svg"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

There is such question: 
[I it possible to include external SVG defs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783374/i-it-possible-to-include-external-svg-defs)
But from those answers I can't understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: SVG doesn't work that way. `<use>` is not the same as a C++ or java include statement, it's just a way to **render** some markup subset.

Comment: Thank you. If so, I wish to know workarounds how to inject defs into SVG scope: 1) `marker-end="url(defs.svg#markerEnd)`, 2) injecting <defs> using JavaScript (my current solution and I don't like it). 3) What else ?

Comment: How did you end up doing it? I'm facing exactly the same need but for referencing filters.
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not solved it. This had very low priority and we postponed it. Seems like this topic is not so interesting for others.