# JS: how to encode an image.png into base64 code for data URI embedding?

Tags: javascript, image, base64, uri, jqxhr

I have several .png bitmaps of different dimensions, by example `./img/dog.png` and `./img/cat.png`. **How to load the `base64` string of my images via JS ?** My expected data is omething like that (but far longer):

```
 data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB9AAAAfQCAYAAACaOMR5AAAgAElEQ…ECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAicCwy83crEe3e04AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

---

**Note:** I wish to get back this string which is my file and just my file, not clipped, nor bigger. I will then embedded it into a SVG `<image>` element such:

```
<image href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB9AYAAACaOMR5AAAgAElyuiRTYUdG
EQVR4XuydB5RdZfW3nZlk0gukk4QUQiCQEEil994RFBCkigpir4j+7V2xgygiIIgggoBUQTqkQIAACQktCamk90m
yfc8492u1/PdqSlMwslaWTNz7zlv2W/d+7f3b5e8r4H/fvzjH+/3pS996akGvva+b37zm4d27Nhx5Wc+85mxNb3r
7xhtvdFi3bl1VWVnZ2ptuumldVVXVIS+88MLAo4466tlPfOIT459//vmOe+2115L61E07D1i2bFmL7373uw/V5/n
GPEOfSs8666zmq1atasa/dbvvvvva73znOwffeOONp5SXl1e89NJLX37xxRfb3HHHHatbtmy5//XXX3/yRz7ykds
+//nPP92Y+nzntddea8+PNchi/Qc/+MHKb33rW4d84xvfeMR62rdvXzl+/Ph1yKjZzjvvvMZnly5duvquu+46sHX
r1mtow7pDDjnk5aFDh64s1F/Czw3+/tvf/nakMq5Pu1555ZW29HXFF7/4xWNffvnl/s2bN6/s1q3bwj/84Q+3xhh
6EMfOmf58uVtqb/9+vXrmz399NPftey33367Ve/evVc7Hxjnqu23336l9X7qU5866Ve/+tWdH/7whz80e/bs7vvo
t9+LyLXlxz72sYfWrl274Z133qlq165dyT//+c8D7r333gN22GGHOdQ1as6cOfvy/Y4DBgy4AXncMWPGDGHsdfgW
...
...
...
vf/nakMq5Pu1555ZW29HXFF7/4xdfgvf/nakMq5Pu1sfgW29HXFF7/4xW">
</image>
```

My end project looks will look like that :)

[image]

See also: https://rugger-demast.codio.io/front/_location_map-en-wikiatlas.html , where you can download the SVG, but the png is currently just a link and will not get downloaded.

Comment: Are you really asking how to convert an image to Base64, or do you have Base64 already, it's really not clear ?=

Comment: I have png or jpg images, [such this one](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/back/01_shaded_relief/shadedrelief.trans2.png). I'am newbie to base64 which I discovered today.

Comment: So you have an image, and you want to convert it to Base64 then ?

Comment: Ok, after few reading, seems I first need to get the base64.

Comment: Seems the question [Getting BLOB data from XHR request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022425/#8022521) is helpful.

Comment: for download see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994554/download-files-like-mega-co-nz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. The solution is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGUsu/116/) and explained as follows.

**0) Objective:** I wish to append something such :

```
<img src="data:[mime type;][charset=<charset>;][base64,][base64 data]"> // formula
<image src='data:image/png;base64,SGVsbG8s...IHdvcmxkIQ='></image>" // shortened example
```

#### 1) PNG images to base 64.

PNGs are stored as [BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blob/info), aka "a collection of binary data stored as a single entity". So I need a BLOB to Base64 converter :

```
var converterEngine = function (input) { // fn BLOB => Binary => Base64 ?
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(input),
          i = uInt8Array.length;
    var biStr = []; //new Array(i);
    while (i--) { biStr[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);  }
    var base64 = window.btoa(biStr.join(''));
    return base64;
};
```

#### 2) Loading the file and converting (data)

```
var getImageBase64 = function (url, callback) {
    // to comment better
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(url), img64;
    xhr.open('GET', url, true); // url is the url of a PNG/JPG image.
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.callback = callback;
    xhr.onload  = function(){
        img64 = converterEngine(this.response); // convert BLOB to base64
        this.callback(null,img64) // callback : err, data
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(){ callback('B64 ERROR', null); };
    xhr.send();
};

// make it looks like other D3js requests
d3.uri = function(url, callback) {
    return getImageBase64(url, callback);
  };
```

#### 3) Run the whole:

I run the function with the callback to append an image element with the base64 URI data.

```
d3.uri('http://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png', function(data){ 
    $("#myImage").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data);  // inject data:image in DOM
} )
```

**Sources:** I got help from [Getting BLOB data from XHR request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022521/1974961), then [demoed there](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xGUsu/116/).

#### Server side

I may actually end up using server-side conversion (sources [this](http://sketchytech.blogspot.fr/2012/12/base64-encoding-of-image-files.html) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)). Possible ways are :

```
echo -n `cat file.png` | base64 > output.txt
openssl base64 < path/to/file.png | tr -d '\n' > output.txt
cat path/to/file.png | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n' > output.txt
openssl base64 -in input.png -out output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load text from a file into a JavaScript object with XMLHttpRequest if you want. Then you can assign the value to the xlink:href attribute for the image element with setAttribute. But the answer to this question is probably what you want.

[Does SVG support embedding of bitmap images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249664/does-svg-support-embedding-of-bitmap-images)

Comment: Do you mean there is a JS function to load a .png as a txt, and I will get the base64 code ?

Comment: I thought you had it as Base64. Is that something you want to do in the browser? There is a JavaScript function called btoa.

Comment: Oh... I already crossed this cat somewhere (intense memory digging)

Comment: My preference would be to convert the image before the browser gets it and load that. But if that isn't your plan, there is this Q&A that describes converting with JavaScript. It probably won't work everywhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022425/getting-blob-data-from-xhr-request