# Alt and Title tags for SVG

Tags: svg

I am adding my images as svg files to my website. How to you add alt and title tags like you do for regular jpg and png images?

This is the code I use to display svg images.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/logo.svg" width="182px" height="199px"></object>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's stopping you from simply using `<img src="img/logo.svg" alt="yourAltText" />`?

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files) has some good info for you.

Even if you don't have a raster fallback, you could use the fallback just for the alt functionality like so:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/logo.svg" width="182px" height="199px">
    <img src="img/logo.svg" width="182px" height="199px" alt="yourAltText" />
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the post. I've tried to the code you've recommended but the title tag doesn't show.

Comment: Ah I didn't add a `title` tag, where did you add it in?

Comment: I just added it within the img tag as normal.

Comment: The img tag is just a fallback if the object doesn't load. Try adding it to both the object and the img if you want to be sure that it has a title