# Can't select svg element with d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am working on a visualization tool that uses a svg image of the brain. Now this svg has paths that are filled with a color. I want to loop over all these paths to set the fill color to white, but for some reason I cannot get the element.

The project can be seen [here](http://medvis.laureif80.eighty.axc.nl/). The svg is inside a `div` and I even assigned an identifier `brain` to the div. The svg itself has an id `svg2`. So far I've tried the following:

```
function clearBrainColors() {
    var brain = d3.select("#svg2");
    console.log(brain);
    var paths = brain.selectAll("path");
    console.log(paths.length);
    brain.selectAll('path').each(function(d,i) { console.log(this); });
}
```

But it outputs null in the array[0] component of the selection and 0 with paths.length.

I've also tried to use lines such as

`var brain = d3.select("#brain svg");` and `var brain = d3.select("#brain svg#svg2");` but those do not work either.

So, how can I select the brain svg using d3?

Comment: isn't the class 'point' your brain ? just looking at the elements in the developer tools. have you got a simple fiddle to look at also ...

Comment: No that would be points inside the scatterplot.

Comment: The brain is in a separate document which you are loading via the `<object>` tag. CSS doesn't apply across documents. Either run the d3 in the SVG itself or make the SVG inline.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well I want to apply css by using javascript (d3), so not directly apply css. But maybe you cannot even reach the svg with Javascript... good point, i'll look into it. Edit: apparently you should be able to, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21503151/1360853

Comment: Indeed, if you get the contained document via javascript you can dig into its CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to put the svg inline as it [apparently speeds things up](http://benfrain.com/selecting-svg-inside-tags-with-javascript/).

The code I used to fill the svg is now:

```
$("#svg2").find("path").each(function(){
       $(this).css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try setTimeOut() , following example

```
setTimeOut(function() {

    var brain = d3.select("#svg2");
    console.log(brain);

}, 1000);
```

this could be the svg is generate on the spot, d3 unable get at that moment.

Hope this help :)