# SVG shape not sharp on non-retina, but sharp on retina

Tags: image, object, svg, resize, retina

```
<img width="80" height="90"  src="/assets/images/shape.svg" />
```

I'm using a SVG inside a `<img />` tag to display a shape with only a border.
On non-retina (left) the SVG image isn't sharp, but on retina it is (right):

[image]

I also tried putting the SVG image in a `<object>`, but the same pixel border appears.. (suggested in: [Do I use <img>, <object>, or <embed> for SVG files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files)).

Anyone with an explanation or fix for this, please? :)

Comment: On what UA? Report it as a bug on the UA's bugtracker (unless it's already been reported)

Comment: @RobertLongson What's UA?

Comment: User Agent - typically a web browser but you might be using Batik or a plug in or some other mechanism