# iron-iconset-svg with external svg files

Tags: svg, polymer

Is it possible to use `<iron-iconset-svg />` with external svg files instead of inlining the svg data ?

I tried like this but that does not seem to work:

Icon definition:

```
<iron-iconset-svg name="my-icons" size="100">
    <svg id="i1" src="/resources/icons/1.svg" />
    ...
</iron-iconset-svg>
```

Icon display:

```
<iron-icon icon="my-icons:i1"></iron-icon>﻿
```

Comment: There's no `src` in `svg`.

Comment: Valid point. I guess the best way will be to write a custom icon element based on the html in the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files