# Even though MIME-Type is set in IIS, cannot disply SVG file

Tags: svg, iis-7.5, mime-types

[IIS MimeTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnOqn.png)

I have an image tag with an svg file:

```
<img src="/uploadedImages/temp/Example.svg?n=9368" alt="testsvg" title="testsvg" align="middle">
```

which won't display in any browser. I can see in Developer Tools that the Content-Type is coming through as application/octet-stream. However, in IIS 7.5, I DO have the MIME-Type set as image/svg+xml (see attached screenshot in link "IIS MimeTypes" above). I also tried setting it in the web.config as follows:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

but that also did not help. What am I missing? How do I get the correct Mime-type to load so that the image can show in the browser?
(By the way, in IE, if I browse to the file's location, the image DOES show. But not in Chrome and Firefox, they merely want to download the file instead of display it.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files

Comment: @Marc, I am not at liberty to change away from the img tag, this has to work as coded.

Comment: Does it work if you omit the ?n=9368

Comment: No, unfortunately not.