# Rendering svg from static assets using d3 in React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, maps, visualization

I want to load a static SVG for a floor plan from my assets, render it to the DOM and then use d3 to modify it to highlight rooms, create tooltips etc. I don't know how I can do this in React at all. You can grab the svg from here https://github.com/hamzanasir/RTCfacilities/blob/master/public/svg/SB-01.svg.

Comment: you might want to check out this other question / answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files

Answer (score 0):

I think your SVG file is converted from AutoCAD-like app's *.dwg file.

If you want highlight some elements(eg: path) you need to give them a distinct marker(like *id* or *class* attribute) so that the **CSS** selector or **d3** can select them. Unfortunately, the converter tool may not aware that. So you need give them markers manually.

Comment: Sorry, I find some ID attributes on some path elements. You can fill a special color to see if it is the room you want highlight. Good luck!

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Sorry but I'm asking how can you render an SVG  from your assets at all?

Comment: @Muhammad Sorry I have no idea about React.