# Google Chrome shows the status of XHR call as (blocked:other)

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting the following status in one of my http call. I haven't seen this status before. All my call are being blocked and no hits are received at server.

I tried looking up for it and found that it might be due to something called Mixed content. Unfortunately, I do not have much idea about that either.

Can someone explain what might be causing this issue and how to get around it. ?

Comment: https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=ResourceRequestBlockedReason::kOther&type=cs

Answer (score 157, accepted):

one possible resolution if you use adblock or any plugins like that, unenable that

Comment: What is more interestting uBlock blocks calls to our domain api, I think because of /googleanalytics endpoint.

Comment: what would I do without stackoverflow, this error is so random. I have 100s of api but all work fine but one stopped

Comment: For me it was PrivacyBadger

Comment: Firefox security settings were blocking APIs for me.

Comment: AdBlock indeed! I'm guessing it had something to do with a particular set of rest URIs that had the word 'affiliation' in them. The rest of the app worked fine.

Comment: For me it was due to noscript extension. I had "disabled noscript globally" using the option in noscript configuration but it was somehow still blocking the script. So I finally disable noscript alltogether and then it worked.

Comment: For me it was the Brave browser. Thank you so much for this comment.

Comment: For me it was Adblocker Ultimate. Thank you

Comment: simly say Disable that :)

Comment: F-Secure Browsing Protection seems to be one "like that"

Comment: Malwarebytes on Chrome was the culprit

Comment: Thanks! For me it was the Honey extension

Answer (score 18):

This massively helped me. Was related to ad blocker.
My ajax url had the word 'advert' in it so the ad blocker

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048381

Comment: Thanks a lot man, my ``advert_template.jpg`` had me debugging for 4 hours

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned mixed content, it may be caused by ajax with http protocol in a https context, which will be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case was caused by the rules in the `Content-Security-Policy` response header

Comment: Same here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was happening because I was including SVG images in my application using the `<object>` tag (which creates a browser iframe) and my application server was setting the `X-Frame-Options` header to `DENY`, so content in iframes was not allowed. I was only able to determine this because Firefox explained the problem in its developer console; I wasn't able to find any more detail about why the content was blocked within Chrome.

The solution is either to include the SVG using a [different method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73156416/2442167) that doesn't create iframes, or to change your `X-Frame-Options` header (either setting it to `SAMEORIGIN` instead or removing it entirely, depending on the origin of the SVG file and your security requirements).