# Refused to display image in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.7.RELEASE app. with Thymeleaf template engine
I hace this piece of code in a Thymeleaf template, but the image does not show up

```
<object data="assets/img/icons/ico_status_up.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <img th:src="@{assets/img/icons/ico_status_up.png}"  alt="UP">
</object>
```

I and see this error in the console of the browser:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/bonanza/pecador/assets/img/icons/ico_status_up.svg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

I use spring-security in my project:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you use Spring Security in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are probably using authconfigured Spring Security module.

As explained in [Spring Security Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-frame-options) :

> A more modern approach to address clickjacking is to use X-Frame-Options header:
>
> **X-Frame-Options: DENY**
>
> The X-Frame-Options response header instructs the browser to prevent any site with this header in the response from being rendered within a frame. **By default, Spring Security disables rendering within an iframe.**

So to configure this behaviour you should configure your Spring Security :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        // ...
        .headers()
            .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin(); // or disable();
    }
}
```

Also I would encourage you to look at SO question which covers topic on what `html` tag to use to display SVG - [Do I use <img>, <object>, or <embed> for SVG files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files)

Comment: I'm trying to display 10 images on a page and out of which 8 images are not getting displayed and is throwing the same error Will it still be because of spring security?