# Using javascript-generated SVG with embedded external SVG as Google Maps icons,

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

So I'm developing a website which uses Google Maps JavaScript API. I have a few markers that I would like to generate an SVG icon for, but this SVG must use JavaScript variables (to display a number on the icon), as well as show an external SVG (such as a FontAwesome icon).

I managed to generate the icons with JavaScript variables as follows:

```
let newIcon = [
    '<svg width="' + size + 'px" height="' + size + 'px" viewBox="0 0 100 110" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >',

    '<ellipse id="circuloExterior" fill="' + mainColor + '" cx="50" cy="50" rx="42.8" ry="42.8"/>',
    '<polygon id="triangulo" fill="' + mainColor + '" stroke="' + mainColor + '" stroke-width="1.6" points="28,83 72,83 50,108"/>',
    '<ellipse id="circuloIntermedio" fill="' + mainColor + '" cx="50" cy="50" rx="41.2" ry="41.2"/>',
    '<ellipse id="circuloInterior" stroke="' + mainColor + '" fill="' + secColor + '" stroke-width="1.6" cx="50" cy="50" rx="32" ry="32"/>',

    '</svg>',
].join('\n');

newIcon = {
    url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(newIcon),
}
```

And then I use `newIcon` as the marker's icon. This is working with no issues.

But, when I try linking to an external SVG that I'd like to add to the icon (along with the existing one), it doesn't work:

```
<image xlink:href="<link to external SVG on the same server>" />
```

I've tried making an SVG file with the exact same external SVG link and it works standalone, so it's not an issue with the `image` tag.

I've also tried explicitly specifying an SVG as a path instead of linking to it, and that works but it's not exactly what I'm looking for:

```
<g transform="translate(30,25) scale(0.13)"><path fill="#000000" d="M128 288c0-6.25-2-12.25-5-17.25-3.25-5-16.5-22-21.75-38.75-0.75-2.75-3.25-4-5.25-4s-4.5 1.25-5.25 4c-5.25 16.75-18.5 33.75-21.75 38.75-3 5-5 11-5 17.25 0 17.75 14.25 32 32 32s32-14.25 32-32zM256 256c0 70.75-57.25 128-128 128s-128-57.25-128-128c0-25.25 7.75-48.75 20.25-68.75 12.75-20 66.25-87.75 86.5-155.25 3.25-10.75 13.25-16 21.25-16s18.25 5.25 21.25 16c20.25 67.5 73.75 135.25 86.5 155.25s20.25 43.5 20.25 68.75z"/></g>
```

Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: I've tried using as icon an SVG with a simple square and an ```image``` referencing another SVG. It works fine when opening it directly in a browser, but when using as an icon only the square shows up. It must be some limitation of Google Maps? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image):

> SVG files displayed with `<image>` are treated as an image: external resources aren't loaded, :visited styles aren't applied, and they cannot be interactive. To include dynamic SVG elements, try `<use>` with an external URL.

I suppose you could take `<use>` or `<object>` like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" version="1.1">
    <object height="200" width="200" data="https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/sprite-9ba8de1b.svg"/>
</svg>
```

More in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files)...

---

But I would instead download the svg from the external source **before** I generate the icon. When you attempt to download it multiple times, it's going to be cached anyways.