# How to load content of `object` tag on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-object

I have an object tag that contains an animated SVG. I show it when the `beforeunload` event is triggered. But it only requests the SVG when it is visible. Is there a way to load the content after the page is loaded and not when the element itself is visible?

This is my html code:

```
<div class="loader-container">
    <object data="/SVG.svg"></object>
</div>
<style>
    .loader-container {
        align-items: center;
        background: #fafafa;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;
    }
</style>
<script>
    jQuery(() => {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
            document.querySelector('.loader-container').style.display = 'flex'
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I suspect this is a result of using the object tag. Try using the img tag or embed tag instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files

Comment: I would use that but this is an animated SVG. It contains script tags which won't be loaded if used inside img tag.

Comment: SVGs do not have script tags, animated or not. So that seems to be your real problem. But I could be wrong.

Comment: They do. You can actually embed script tags inside an SVG file. I used https://www.svgator.com/ to create one. It gives you an option of doing it with css. But it was not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
visibility: hidden;
```

instead of

```
display:none;
```

Comment: It will do the trick but not sure if it should be the solution. It will just block all the interaction with other elements, which is something I assume no one wants.

Comment: you can change the size to width:0 height:0 when it is hidden. Then you can reset it to 100% when it is shown...