# Onclick event on Object HTML Tag doesn't work, workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, object, svg, onclick

So I have an SVG imported via the `<object>` tag and it has a `onclick="functionName();` attached to it, but it doesn't appear to work. So I tried adding the following script in the SVG:

```
<svg tag here etc
<defs>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <![CDATA[
            document.addEventListener('click', test());
            ]]>
        </script>
    <linearGradient id="bbc50e5b-4734-4535-94bd-b30475bdd571" data-name="Testingspace" x1="15" y1="310" x2="320" y2="5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ccc"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
the rest of SVG here
```

My HTML:

```
<object id="sidebartoggle" data="graphics/test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onclick="toggleSidebar();" style="top:50%;right:1%;position:fixed;display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;width:500px;transform: translateX(99%); z-index:9999999;" >
            </object>
```

...but it simply doesn't work. What's the required workaround here? What should I do to accomplish my goal - bind a click event on the SVG, which executes a function from the JS file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. You likely want to move the script OUTSIDE the svg

Comment: Also this is not the way to assign an event handler.
`document.addEventListener('click', test());` since it executes the test immediately
perhaps you meant `document.addEventListener('click', test);` or `document.getElementById("objectID").addEventListener('click', test);`

Comment: I am not new to Stack Overflow.. I've changed it to simply `test` and yes that's what I had in mind, but it still doesn't work. And no I want to have the JS in the SVG so that I don't need more code to first get the .contentDocument and etc

Comment: So if you are not new, then please post a [mcve] instead of `<svg tag here etc
<defs>` - you did not even post the object tag - it is very unlikely you can have JS embedded in svg loaded via object

Comment: And yes, you need to access the object from [outside the object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21503151/295783) unless you load an HTML file in an object or iframe instead

Comment: Updated the question. So what I'm trying to accomplish (execute the SVG JS Code, which executes a function from a "global" JS file) is impossible?

Comment: You could insert the object from the js file and then bind the click there too

Comment: The object is too complex to be meddled with JS..

Comment: Change the test() in your SVG file to parent.test()

Comment: @RobertLongson `parent.test();` doesn't appear to work apparently :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onclick event won't be bound to your object, since you're actually clicking/targeting the object's inner content (svg DOM).

As a workaround you could apply a css `pointer-events:none` to your object element and bind your click event to an auxiliary wrapping element.

```js
function toggleSidebar(){
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

```css
.svg-wrp{
   cursor:pointer; 
}

.svgObject{
    display:inline-block;
  font-size:36px;
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
  background-color:transparent;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>css: "pointer-events:none" – click enabled</h3>
<div class="svg-wrp" onclick="toggleSidebar()" >
  <object class="svgObject" id="sidebartoggle01" data="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20' class='cross'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='grey' points='11.649 9.882 18.262 3.267 16.495 1.5 9.881 8.114 3.267 1.5 1.5 3.267 8.114 9.883 1.5 16.497 3.267 18.264 9.881 11.65 16.495 18.264 18.262 16.497'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" type="image/svg+xml" style="pointer-events:none" ></object>
</div>

<h3>Original &lt;object&gt; – click event is not available</h3>
<div class="svg-wrp" onclick="toggleSidebar()" >
  <object class="svgObject" id="sidebartoggle01" data="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20' class='cross'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='grey' points='11.649 9.882 18.262 3.267 16.495 1.5 9.881 8.114 3.267 1.5 1.5 3.267 8.114 9.883 1.5 16.497 3.267 18.264 9.881 11.65 16.495 18.264 18.262 16.497'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" type="image/svg+xml"  ></object>
</div>
```

**Edit: `<script>` tag in svg**

You can do this [MDN Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/script)
But you'll encounter scoping issues.
If you need to call globally defined functions by clicking a svg element, you might add an eventListener after loading the object.

**SVG**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <script>
  // <![CDATA[
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    function getColor () {
      const R = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')
      const G = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')
      const B = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16).padStart(2,'0')
      return `#${R}${G}${B}`
    }

    document.querySelector('rect').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.target.style.fill = getColor()
    })
  })
  // ]]>
  </script>
  <rect id="bg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ccc"></rect>
</svg>
```

**html**

```
<object class="svgObject" id="sidebartoggle" data="script.svg"  type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
```

**js**

```
function test(){
    console.log('test')
}  

var svgObject = document.getElementById("sidebartoggle");
// get svg content 
svgObject.addEventListener("load",function(){
    // get the inner DOM of svg
    var svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;
    var bg = svgDoc.querySelector('#bg');
    // bind click event
    bg.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        test();
    });
});
```

However scripts added to svg files might also be considered as suspicious in some environments (e.g. wordpress).
Some file sanitizing filters will strip script tags from svg.

Comment: Can you define the function in the SVG as well? Or is that a no-go?