# Unable to find svg files

Tags: wordpress, svg, twig

I'm Facing Weird issue with svg files and twig

It says Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Unable to find template

```
{% set logo = Image(options.logo_foot) %}               
    {% if logo.file_loc %}  
        {{ source(logo.file_loc) }}  
    {% endif %}
```

seems more likely to windows issue
on mac everythings works fine

Comment: Any reason why you are using the function `source` here? This is usually used to display the source of a template located in a registered views folder. What is your expected output? - [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/source.html)

Comment: Yes  Basically it will  get the svg file from upload folder on mac same code works but on windows not working

Comment: What do you mean with "On mac it is working". Twig is rendered server-side. Are you testing this on two different servers?

Comment: i'm using local by flywheel    live server its fine

Comment: nah everything is on  my local machine

Comment: it returns the path of the svg file but the error message says it cant find that file although the file is present

Comment: As I said, `source` expects the file to be inside the `Views` folder. Is this the case?

Comment: No   as this return the path  for the svg file  inside brackets -->  {{ source(directory ~ '/src/images/icons/hex.svg') }}    then it  get file from upload folder and it display on the page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I use <img>, <object>, or <embed> for SVG files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files)