# Using svg as img src in gatsby fails in netlify build

Tags: javascript, svg, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

So I have an assets folder in src. This contains an SVG of my logo.

I import it in a component using:

```js
import Logo from '/src/assets/logo.svg';
```

This is 100% the right path, and running the local npm run develop server the SVG loads fine. Now, when I push changes to the repository, so netlify builds the site, I get an error:

```
4:02:22 PM: failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 25.063s
4:02:22 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
4:02:22 PM: Can't resolve '../assets/logo.svg' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
4:02:22 PM: If you're trying to use a package make sure that '../assets/logo.svg' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
```

I'm not trying to use it as a component (IF POSSIBLE), just put an img src as the SVG. However, as you can see it fails in the building process. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your `gatsby build` local working?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provide the code that fails. Do you use `gatsby-image` for it or just HTML `img` tag?

If it is HTML tag, you can try it with object tag.
Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482962/8204500) about what to use with SVG files on Stack Oveflow and a [basic usage](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) of object tag.